# uncaught reference error $ is not defined in datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, referenceerror

Please help me, again. Because I'm newbie.
i've problem with my datatable. when i load in my chrome, it give me feedback like this:

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

i try to add this code, but it also doesnt work. what must i do?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(document).ready(function(){

siswa.php code:

```html
<?php
$this->load->view('admin/head.php');
?>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Data Berhasil Dimasukkan</h4>
          <br>
          <a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo site_url("admin/nav_admin");?>" role="button" float="right">Back To</a>
          <br>
          <br>
     <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th style="width:20%">NISN</th>
                     <th style="width:35%">Nama</th>
                     <th style="width:15%">Jenis Kelamin</th>
                     <th style="width:20%">Nilai</th>
                     <th style="width:20%">Jurusan</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
            <tbody>
       <?php
       if( ! empty($import)){ // Jika data pada database tidak sama dengan empty (alias ada datanya)
        foreach($import as $data){ // Lakukan looping pada variabel siswa dari controller
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$data->nisn."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$data->nama."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$data->jenis_kelamin."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$data->nilai_rata."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$data->kode_jurusan."</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
        }
       } else{ // Jika data tidak ada
        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Data tidak ada</td></tr>";
       }
       ?>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> // uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined in datatable
  $(function(){
    $("table").DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

here's the head.php code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Halaman Admin</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/stylesidebar.css');?>">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: It's caused by jQuery's $ missing. Enqueue the script and that should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Put your js code in:

```
jQuery(function($){

});
```

Comment: under script tag